# Error save data google place autocomplete Angular 2

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, google-places-api, angular2-forms

Error when try save data using google place autocomplete.
This error:
Uncaught Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!

```
     </div><form #formEndereco="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
     <select class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="options.componentRestrictions.country" name="options.componentRestrictions.country" >
    <option *ngFor="let country of CountryCodes" [value]="country.Code">{{country.Name}}</option>
</select>

    <table id="address">
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Street</td>

        <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"
              #street=ngModel [(ngModel)] = "address.street" name="street"></td>

      </tr>
</table>
   <input type="submit" value="{{titulo}}" class="btn btn-success"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: how did you defined address ?

Comment: I solve preblem, in realy my problem in the CORS for  ausing localhost.